# Sorting JSON object based on value type [array or numeral or string]

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I am receiving a JSON object from server in the following format:

```
obj = {
    field1: "ONE",
    field2: "TWO",
    field3: [THREE1,THREE2,THREE3]
    field4: "FOUR",
    field5: [FIVE1,FIVE2,FIVE3]
};
```

Even though i am sending the object in order that is , arrays at the bottom and strings at the top of the object but i am receiving not in ordered form. Is there any way to sort this in the following format.

```
obj = {
    field1: "ONE",
    field2: "TWO",
    field4: "FOUR",
    field3: [THREE1,THREE2,THREE3],
    field5: [FIVE1,FIVE2,FIVE3]
};
```

Currently i am using the following method, and its working but may be there is a better way.

```
obj = {
    field1: "ONE",
    field2: "TWO",
    field3: [THREE1,THREE2,THREE3]
    field4: "FOUR",
    field5: [FIVE1,FIVE2,FIVE3]
};

var strObj = {};
var arrObj = {};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  console.table("Key : " + key + ", Value : " + obj[key]);
  if (!(obj[key] instanceof Array)) {
    strObj[key] = obj[key];
  }
});
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  console.table("Key : " + key + ", Value : " + obj[key]);
  if (obj[key] instanceof Array) {
    arrObj[key] = obj[key];
  }
});

obj = { ...strObj, ...arrObj };
console.log(obj);`
```

Comment: A) There's no such thing as a "JSON object" B) That's not even JSON

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I think it's fair to call the dictionary/map construct in JSON an "object," given how it corresponds to `Object` in JS. Though, I agree that once OP `JSON.parse`s that JSON string from the server, we're no longer strictly dealing with JSON per se.

Comment: OP, why do you need the keys to be ordered? A JSON object, semantically, is unordered. Maybe instead of retrofitting `Object` with the ordering guarantees you need, choose a data structure that natively supports it, e.g. send an array of key/ value pairs from the server, and read it into a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: @wbadart the ordering was needed to create a csv using that JSON object and the csv service required the arrays to be at the end of the JSON object, well, i did manage to order them, but at the end i used array of key/value pairs and mapped them accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can you point out the original question, may be i'll find a a better solution.

Comment: @Ahmed - Sorry, I don't understand...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the object based on whether the value is an array or not. Then use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to create a new object from the sorted entries

```js
const obj = {
  field1: "ONE",
  field2: "TWO",
  field3: ["THREE1", "THREE2", "THREE3"],
  field4: "FOUR",
  field5: ["FIVE1", "FIVE2", "FIVE3"]
};

const sortedEntries = Object.entries(obj)
                      .sort((a, b) => Array.isArray(a[1]) - Array.isArray(b[1]));
                      
const newObj = Object.fromEntries(sortedEntries)

console.log(newObj)
```